# python: after function ,array doesnot change

Tags: python

I want to find K minimal elements in a array:

```
def partition(A):
    pivotIndex = len(A)-1
    storeIndex = 0
    for i in xrange(len(A)):
        if A[i] < A[pivotIndex]:
            A[i], A[storeIndex] = A[storeIndex], A[i]
            storeIndex += 1
    A[storeIndex], A[pivotIndex] = A[pivotIndex], A[storeIndex]
    print A
    return storeIndex

def findminiK(array, k):
    mini = 0
    while mini < k:
        if mini < k-1 :
            print array, "---"
            mini = partition(array[mini:])
            print array, "++"
        elif mini == k-1:
            return array[:k]
        else :
            mini = partition(array[:mini])
    return array[k]
```

In my opinoin, after partition, array will change.

e.g:
Original array is `[3,4,7,5,9,9,6]`
After partition, array will become `[3,4,5,6,7,9,8]`
But I find the array does not change.
Who can give me some suggestion?

Comment: okay, I have found the problem, array[:] is not the same array, just some copy of it

Comment: The best way to do this is with a heap: https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html

Comment: yes, i know, but, using partition is also another way to solve this problem, so i want to try ^_^